# Cannot show a Toast in Android

Tags: android, toast

I want show Toast when `toast()` is called, but it's not showing a Toast.

This is my code:

```
void callcalltoast() {
    ...
    calltoast();
    ...
}
void calltoast() {
    ...
    toast();
    ...
}
void toast() {
    Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"this is toast",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I call toast in two other functions:

First call `callcalltoast()` then `calltoast()` then call `toast()`

And this is log:

```
08-04 14:47:34.390: I/LOG(1796): this is toast
08-04 14:47:34.430: I/Choreographer(1796): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 14:47:34.451: W/InputMethodManagerService(285): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41a1c750 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@419ff990
```

I have tested using this:

```
void toast() {
    Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is toast",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

this

```
void toast() {
    Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
    Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and

```
void toast() {
    Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"this is toast",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But its not showing a Toast.

Comment: try to pass activity context instead of base context

Comment: pass getApplicationContext() or getActivity() instead of base context

Comment: show code where you call toast()

Comment: i'm edit post,i call toast in two other functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

you can declare global variables `Context context;` and `context=MainActivity.this;` when Activity Create then when you call toast you can use context  like `toast(context);`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        context=MainActivity.this;

        callcalltoast();
        ...
    }
    void callcalltoast() {
    ...
    calltoast();
    ...
    }
    void calltoast() {
        ...
        toast(context);
        ...
    }
    void toast(Context context) {
        Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
        Toast.makeText(context,"this is toast",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `getBaseContext()`. If you are in Activity, just pass `this` as context, alternatively you can use `getApplicationContext()` to get one

Comment: i test it `getApplicationContext()` and `this` but not work

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
public enum Toaster {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public void postMessage(Context context, final String message) {
        handler.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And then this:

```
Toaster.INSTANCE.postMessage(this, "this is toast");
```

It should work that way from any thread. Normally I just have a singleton holder for the ApplicationContext though and I'd provide that as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to pass the Context to function like below

```
void toast(Context context) {
   Log.i("LOG", "this is toast");
   Toast.makeText(context,"this is toast",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

for calling this function just write

this is when you call it in activity

```
toast(Your_Activity_Name.this);
```

in your case it will be like below

```
 toast(MainActivity .this);
```

and if you use that in fragment then

```
 toast(getActivity());
```

> "Skipped 90 frames!" the possibility can be is that you are testing your app on emulator if yes then don't worry about that. and if you are testing on real device then this log is not because of showing but because of your other code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callcall();


}
private void callcall() {
    .....
    calltoast();
    .....
}

private void calltoast() {
    .....
    toast();
    .....
}

private void toast(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: i test it `getApplicationContext()`  but not work and can not use `getActivity()` and `this.Activity`

Comment: tell me you are using activity or fragment or other

Comment: i use activity and `toast() ` is in MainActivity